# Where to find tutorials for scaladoc 2?

Tags: scala, scaladoc

I binged or googled for scaladoc 2.0 tutorial or example, I could not find anything, in fact not even a link to official scaladoc 2.0 documentation.
Anyone know where to find one?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[docs.scala-lang.org](http://docs.scala-lang.org/index.html) is a more recent source of "Community-driven documentation for Scala" (thanks to the initiative lead by [Heather Miller](http://heather.miller.am/blog/2011/07/improving-scala-documentation/)).
(as edited by [Martin Konicek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90998/martin-konicek) in [David James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109618/david-james)'s original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7543210/6309)) 
The [Scaladoc page](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/scaladoc.html) is quite up-to-date.

[Martin Konicek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90998/martin-konicek) asks in the comment how to make a simple Javadoc-like `{@link}`.
(And  `{@link}` isn't mentioned in [`scala.tools.nsc.ast.DocComments.scala`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ast/DocComments.scala))

He mentions that Scaladoc uses `[[fullyQualifiedName]]` instead of `{@link}`.

---

Initial answer (July/Sept 2011)

Right now, the most complete source of information I know about Scaladoc2 is in the new **[scala-lang.org Wiki](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Scaladoc)**.

[David James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109618/david-james) mentions in the comments the [Syntax page](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Syntax), and the [Tags and Annotations](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Tags+and+Annotations).

The **[author page](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=294986)** has examples, including a [what's new section](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Scaladoc+New):

> Authors of documentation no longer have to use HTML tags in their comments.
>   Instead, **Scaladoc supports a wiki-like syntax** very similar to that used in Trac.
>   In general, Scaladoc authors should no longer use HTML tags in documentation as Scaladoc may in the future also generate documentation in other formats than HTML.

Comment: After digging around, I've found more content in the wiki you mentioned: [Syntax](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Syntax) and [Tags and Annotations](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Tags+and+Annotations).

Comment: @MartinKonicek Note that https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ast/DocComments.scala doesn't mention `@link`.

Comment: @VonC Yes, now I know Scaladoc uses [[fullyQualifiedName]] instead of {@link}.

Comment: @Martin excellent. Do you have an example of ScalaDoc with that tag used in it? I have edited the answer to include up-to-date links and your question about `{@link}`

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a Scaladoc HOWTO over on github [here](http://keithpinson.github.com/Scaladoc-HOWTO/api/index.html#docSample.package).

It's a how-to written with Scaladoc itself so it serves as an example.  I placed extra emphasis on how to get the package documentation to show up in your API, as this is not very clear in the official documentation.

Comment: I noticed that you frequently used `/*#! scaladoc */` in your source. Is this important?

Comment: No the !# notation is not required by Scaladoc.  You may ignore it.  It is meant to flag the type of coded comment that the file contains.

Answer (score 4):

The [Scala Style Guide](http://davetron5000.github.com/scala-style/index.html) has a [nice introductory page on scaladoc](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/scaladoc.html). I'd recommend it over the scala-lang.org wiki mentioned in @VonC's answer.

Comment: I'd recommend this resource over all the others as well.

Answer (score 3):

A condensed full example:

```
/** Creates [[mypackage.Person]] instances, taking a `String` argument. */
object Person {
  /** Create a [[mypackage.Person]] with a given name.
  *
  * This is another paragraph (note the empty line above) containing '''bold''',
  * ''italic'', `monospace`, __underline__, ^superscript^, and ,,subscript,,.
  * 
  * Example:
  * {{{
  * val person = Person("Bill")
  * }}}
  *
  * @param name their name
  * @return a new Person instance
  */
  def apply(name: String) = {}
}
```

Note that Scaladoc 2.9 **does not support [[links]] to methods** (like **Javadoc**'s `{@link type#instanceMethod(int, String)}` or `{@link type.staticMethod()}`).

Answer (score 0):

This is the best Scaladoc guide I have found: https://gist.github.com/VladUreche/8396624.  It is markdown text, so download it and use a markdown viewer plugin for your browser or paste it into http://markdownlivepreview.com/ to read it.